# Firebase auth error: `CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND`

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting a `CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND` when I try to sign into my Firebase application. I'm aware that I need to enable a sign in method via the Firebase console. I have triple checked that the sign in methods have been enabled; see screenshot below.

[image]

I have also tried disabling and re-enabling the providers, but this does not help. Is it possible that something was misconfigured when I enabled auth? If I understood the Google Cloud console, I'm sure I could fix it myself, but I'm not even sure where to begin looking.

Comment: Hello, I am running with the same issue. How did you fix it?

Comment: I would also like to know how you fixed it. @CarlinoGonzalez, have you found a solution?